# Options values of attribute "visibility"

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, default-values

I am looking for the option values for the attribute visibility. We have a import script running, which is delivering all articles to magento and automatically sets the visibility for simple products to "Katalog and Search" which is value 4.

So now I want to change that to make the simple products visible just through "Search". I was searching for the value within the MySQL database but couldn´t find anything yet.
Does anyone of you know or have an idea in which table to find that option values of visbility?

Would be great if anybody could help me on this.

Answer (score 13):

These are constants, held in the class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility`

```
const VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE    = 1;
const VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG     = 2;
const VISIBILITY_IN_SEARCH      = 3;
const VISIBILITY_BOTH           = 4;
```

It's preferred to use them, and not the values directly.

Comment: It works, tanks very much.