# How to override a static method in Magento2

Tags: magento2, overrides, custom, methods, visibility

Plugin Interceptors and overriding with preference does not work on static methods.

Need to override **getOptionArray** method in **Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility**  to return a custom visibility

```
/**
     * Retrieve option array
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getOptionArray()
    {
        return [
            self::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE => __('Not Visible Individually'),
            self::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG => __('Catalog'),
            self::VISIBILITY_IN_SEARCH => __('Search'),
            self::VISIBILITY_BOTH => __('Catalog, Search')
        ];
    }
```

Any other way this can be achieved ?

Comment: No. I'm asking how to add a new visibility option. getOption array being a static method cannot be modified with interceptors or preference.

Comment: Sorry, I marked wrong question. This one should help you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134386/how-to-add-custom-visibility-option-in-visibility-attribute-in-products-in-magen

Comment: That one doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Anyone? i've been stuck with this for 2-3 days. Any alternative way to add visibility option ?

Answer (score 2):

Overriding only `getOptionArray()` is not just enough because if you see in Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility at line 107, 120 & 134, `getOptionArray()` is called with *`self`*.Self will always call the original method rather than new one, hence you simply need to copy and paste `getAllOption()`, `getAllOptions()` & `getOptionText()` in your overridden Model Class (Same where you have overriden `getOptionArray()`)